# Find out multiple definitions of a field in a class

Tags: python, class

How can I find out that a class have multiple definitions for a field in its body? For eg:

```py
class cl:
    a = 'abc'
    a = 'qa'

print cl.a
```

here we get `cl.a` printed as `'qa'`. However is there any way to raise an exception in such cases or find out that the field had multiple definitions.
I tried looking up in class dict and also used the `dir()` method to get the list of all attributes. None of them show multiple definitions for the field.

Comment: So you want `cl.a` to return something like `['abc', 'qa']`?

Comment: Do you really need this for class variables, or would it be OK to only do it for instance variables (e.g. `self.a` inside a method)?

Comment: @Chris it would be more better if i can catch this and raise an exception.

Comment: @Blckknght my usecase is currently for class fields but I am equally interested in knowing how this can be handled for instance variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A metaclass's `__prepare__` method can return an alternative mapping type to be used as the class's attribute dictionary. That mapping could allow assignments to any new key, but raise an exception if an assignment is attempted again when for a key that already exists in the namespace.

```
class AssignOnceDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            raise Exception("Duplicate assignment")
        super().__setitem__(key, value)

class AssignOnceMeta(type):
    def __prepare__(name, bases, **kwargs):
        return AssignOnceDict()


class cl(metaclass=AssignOnceMeta):
    a = 1
    a = 2 # raises an exception
```

Comment: That's right, it was one of the additions proposed in [PEP 3115](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/), and added in version 3.0.

Comment: Is there any workaroud for 2.7 which you are aware of @Blckknght

Comment: @sumit: No, there's nothing you can do in Python 2, as the metaclass doesn't have a chance to get involved in the class creation until after the multiple assignments have already been made.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't such a thing as "having multiple definitions". The code inside the `class` block runs at the time that the class is created, and then the resulting variables become attributes of the class. It's the same as if you wrote at the top level

```
a = 'abc'
a = 'qa'
```

and then wanted to find out after the fact that there had been multiple assignments; there is no history to consult (unless you somehow create it yourself, as the assignments happen).

Comment: Is there some way to trace this out in the meta class of the given class as it is during that time the class is getting created.